# Where is the source code in Rails for "//= require lightbox-bootstrap"?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets, lightbox2

So I have lightbox2 installed in Rails via GEM file.  It is referenced in application.js with:

`//= require lightbox-bootstrap`

I feel dumb but where is the source file to edit?  It works 100% and is compiled as part of application js but there is not actual js file anywhere to edit.

Comment: Why would you need to edit it? It works, leave it at that :P

Answer (score 2):

A simple terminal command `bundle show lightbox-bootstrap` will show you where the file is located.